# Setting UIButton titleEdgeInsets and imageEdgeInsets is slow with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit, autolayout

I have a view with a couple of buttons, various sizes. All of them has a title and an image. I wanted to have the image on top, the title on the bottom, centered. This works fine with the following code:

```c
- (void)centerAlignImageAndTextForButton:(UIButton*)button
{
    CGFloat spacing = 5;
    CGSize imageSize = button.imageView.frame.size;
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height + spacing), 0);
    CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + spacing), 0, 0, -titleSize.width);
}
```

However, I notice a little pause before entering this view. Time Profiler in Instruments shows, that 99% of the time spent in viewDidLoad is caused by calling my method for the buttons:

```
283.0ms  -[XViewController viewDidLoad]
282.0ms    -[XViewController centerAlignImageAndTextForButton:]
141.0ms      -[UIButton imageView]
 98.0ms        -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
141.0ms      -[UIButton titleLabel]
103.0ms        -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
```

Various layout related things are called within `[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]`, like `[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) recursiveLayoutEngineDidChange]` or `[NSLayoutConstraint addToEngine]`.

I know it would be possible to set these insets in Interface Builder, but not only that is a tedious work (need to 'guess' the width of the text); the app will also be localized, so the insets that are good for one language, won't be for another where text size differs (I'm using base localization for storyboards, and .strings files instead of duplicating the whole storyboard for each language). So for me it seems setting the insets programmatically is the way to go, but the lag it causes isn't really acceptable.

Any thoughts how this could resolved?

Comment: Why aren't you setting them on `layoutSubViews`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moving all the `centerAlignImageAndTextForButton` calls from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` reduces the loading time from the previous 283 millisecs to 18 millisecs (1 millisecs for `viewDidLoad` and 17 millisecs for `viewDidLayoutSubviews`).

However, I'm a bit puzzled, why is it so expensive to set those insets from `viewDidLoad`...

Comment: Perhaps because at viewDidLoad, none of your layout has been performed, so more work has to be done? In viewDidLayout... the bulk of your layout is already done, so adjusting the insets is a tweak rather than a full layout. That's a guess. BTW, if you're interested in edge insets in buttons, I've recently written about them (with a sample project) here: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/03/12/uibutton-edge-insets/

Comment: Yup, stumbled upon on that post while searching for a solution. Your guess makes sense, some similiar thought came to my mind when found the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method in the documentation, that's why I (luckily) tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with a slow call to `titleLabel` from `awakeFromNib` in custom `UIButton` subclass. Moving the code to view controller was undesirable due to a large number and/or nontrivial life-cycle of the buttons. Moving the code to `layoutSubviews` did not help. Eventually I moved the code to `didMoveToSuperview` and it solved the problem.

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```